# how to set up an automatic compilation of test classes?

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, intellij-13, sbt-idea

Intellij idea not compiles special classes when running test. Now I run the compilation manually via activator console. How can I customize the intellij idea to run automatically when start a compilation of test?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you right but you can try to right click your test class and choose "Run [your_class]". It will compile the needed classes.

Comment: it does not work for me. Test classes are located in the test-classes not compiled, only classes

Comment: What kind of project/directory structure you have? Is it a maven project?